# Spectral Measures: Multi Version (III)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

*This question is only Q&A!*

**Problem**

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a normal operator:
$$N:\mathcal{D}(N)\to\mathcal{H}:\quad N^*N=NN^*$$

And its spectral measure:
$$E:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C})\to\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad N=\int\lambda\mathrm{d}E(\lambda)$$

Denote for shorthand:
$$\mathcal{S}_\varphi:=\overline{\langle\{E(A)\varphi_0:A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C})\}\rangle}$$

By the previous thread:
$$\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{H}:\quad\mathcal{H}=\sum_{\alpha\in\mathcal{A}}\mathcal{S}_\alpha=:\sum_\alpha\mathcal{S}_\alpha$$

Denote for shorthand:
$$\nu_\alpha:=\nu_{\alpha}(A)=\|E(A)\alpha\|^2$$

Introduce the measure space:*
$$\Omega:=\coprod_\alpha\mathbb{C}_\alpha\cong\mathbb{C}\times\mathcal{A}:\quad\nu(A):=\sum_\alpha\nu_\alpha(\iota_\alpha^{-1}A)$$

> Then one has:
>   $$M_\eta:\mathcal{D}(M_\eta)\to\mathcal{L}^2(\nu):\quad N=U^{-1}M_\eta U$$

How can I prove this?

**Reference**

This is the final thread!

**See the thread: [Borel Measures: Coproduct](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1337020/79762)*

Comment: If you're making like a series or something you should at least motivate each post and link the previous parts! All I see in here is formulas + formulas... The titles don't help either.

Comment: @hjhjhj57: Hmm yes good idea. Thanks!

Comment: @hjhjhj57: I gave a motivation as comment. Do you think this is okay so?

Comment: This thread deals with the more precise reducibility of normal unbounded operators instead of cyclicity. *(For further details see: Reducing Spaces)*

Comment: I don't think I am a reference for this, but as you're probably doing this to help someone who might need it in the future you should keep in mind how clear it is. When I write down something for other people I always think about the books I like the most and try to imitate some of their characteristics. The only thing most of these books have in common is that they have way more text than formulas. It's not always easy to follow this as a guideline, but it certainly makes a text more readable, understandable, and enjoyable.

Comment: @hjhjhj57: I do it merely for my satisfaction. :) *But I was never really a fan of to much text...*

Comment: Then do it as you like it best in your own style :) I just shared how *I* like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Embedding**

Consider the embeddings:
$$J_\alpha:\mathcal{S}_\alpha\to\mathcal{H}:\quad J_\beta^*J_\alpha=\delta_{\beta\alpha}1_\alpha\quad J_\alpha J_\alpha^*=P_\alpha$$

Construct the unitary map:
$$U\varphi:=(J_\alpha^*\varphi)_\alpha\quad V(\varphi_\alpha)_\alpha:=\sum_\alpha J_\alpha\varphi_\alpha$$

Indeed they are inverses:*
$$VU\varphi=\sum_\alpha J_\alpha J_\alpha^*\varphi=\sum_\alpha P_\alpha\varphi=\varphi$$
$$(UV(\varphi_\alpha)_\alpha)_\beta=(J_\beta^*\sum_\alpha J_\alpha\varphi_\alpha)_\beta=(\varphi_\beta)_\beta$$

*(Continuity can been used!)*

**Reducibility**

Denote for readability:
$$N_\alpha:=J_\alpha^*NJ_\alpha\quad E_\alpha(A):=J_\alpha^*E(A)J_\alpha$$

By reducibility:
$$E(A)P_\alpha=P_\alpha E(A)\implies N_\alpha=\int\lambda_\alpha\mathrm{d}E_\alpha(\lambda_\alpha)$$

By the previous thread:
$$M_\mathrm{id}^\alpha:\mathcal{D}(M_\mathrm{id}^\alpha)\to\mathcal{L}^2(\nu_\alpha):\quad N_\alpha=U_\alpha^{-1}M_\mathrm{id}^\alpha U_\alpha$$

By reducibility:
$$E(A)P_\alpha=P_\alpha\implies P_\alpha N\subseteq NP_\alpha$$

That gives also:*
$$\mathcal{D}(N)=\sum_\alpha\mathcal{D}(N)\cap\mathcal{S}_\alpha:\quad N\mathcal{S}_\alpha\subseteq\mathcal{S}_\alpha$$

So one obtains:*
$$(UNV(\varphi_\alpha)_\alpha)_\beta=(J_\beta^*N\sum_\alpha J_\alpha\varphi_\alpha)_\beta=(J_\beta^*NJ_\beta\varphi_\beta)_\beta=(N_\beta\varphi_\beta)_\beta$$

In terms of operators:
$$UNV=\bigoplus_\alpha N_\alpha=\bigoplus_\alpha U_\alpha^{-1}M_\mathrm{id}^\alpha U_\alpha=\left(\bigoplus_\alpha U_\alpha^{-1}\right)\left(\bigoplus_\alpha M_\mathrm{id}^\alpha\right)\left(\bigoplus_\alpha U_\alpha\right)$$

*(This is a checkpoint!)*

**Identification**

Consult the unitary map:
$$\Phi:\mathcal{L}^2(\Omega,\nu)\to\bigoplus_\alpha\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{C}_\alpha,\nu_\alpha):\quad h\mapsto(h\circ\iota_\alpha)_\alpha$$

Moreover it is algebraic:
$$\Phi(hh')=\Phi(h)\Phi(h')\quad\Phi(\overline{h})=(\overline{\Phi(h)_\alpha})_\alpha$$

Define the function:
$$\eta:=\Phi^{-1}(\mathrm{id_\alpha})_\alpha:\quad M_\eta h=\Phi^{-1}\left(\bigoplus_\alpha M_\mathrm{id}^\alpha\right)\Phi h$$

All together gives:
$$N=V\left(\bigoplus_\alpha U_\alpha^{-1}\right)\Phi M_\eta\Phi^{-1}\left(\bigoplus_\alpha U_\alpha\right)U$$

Concluding the assertion.

**See the thread: [Reducing Spaces: Decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1337227/79762)*