# Reducing Spaces: Decompostion

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

*This thread is only Q&A!*

**Problem**

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a normal operator:
$$N:\mathcal{D}(N)\to\mathcal{H}:\quad N^*N=NN^*$$

Regard a decomposition:
$$\mathcal{S}_\lambda\leq\mathcal{H}:\quad\mathcal{H}=\sum_\lambda\mathcal{S}_\lambda$$

Suppose they reduce:
$$P_\lambda N\subseteq NP_\lambda$$

Then one has:
$$\mathcal{D}(N)=\sum_\lambda\mathcal{S}_\lambda\cap\mathcal{D}(N):\quad N\mathcal{S}_\lambda\subseteq\mathcal{S}_\lambda$$

Especially it holds:
$$\varphi\in\mathcal{D}(N):\quad P_{\lambda_0}N\sum_\lambda P_\lambda\varphi=P_{\lambda_0}NP_{\lambda_0}\varphi$$

How can I check this?

**Reference**

This thread is a lemma for: [Spectral Measures: Multi Version (III)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1337158/79762)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Domain**

For the domain:
$$P_\lambda N\subseteq NP_\lambda\implies P_\lambda\mathcal{D}\subseteq\mathcal{D}$$

So one obtains
$$\varphi\in\mathcal{D}:\quad\varphi=\sum_\lambda P_\lambda\varphi\in\sum_\lambda\mathcal{S}_\lambda\cap\mathcal{D}$$

*(That allows to continue!)*

**Operator**

Regard index sets:
$$\#\Lambda<\infty:\quad\lambda_0\in\Lambda$$

Then one obtains:
$$\|P_{\lambda_0}N\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}P_\lambda\varphi-P_{\lambda_0}NP_{\lambda_0}\varphi\|=\|P_{\lambda_0}N\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda\setminus\{\lambda_0\}}P_\lambda\varphi\|=\|\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda\setminus\{\lambda_0\}}P_{\lambda_0}NP_\lambda\varphi\|=0$$

Concluding the assertion.